# How can type a button including an icon with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to type a button component where all of them have to get a title, but some don't get an icon.
This icon comes from **"@expo/vector-icons"**. What should I do when I put the component display an icon too?

Like: `<Button icon={<FontAwesome name="icon-name" size={24} colo="color"} title="Title here" />`

My actual code:

```
type IButtonProps = TouchableOpacityProps & {
    title: string;
    icon?: any;
}

function Button({ title, icon }: IButtonProps) {
    return(
        <Container>
            <Text>
                {title}
            </Text>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Button;
```

and here is when the component is used for display

```
 <Button 
                    title="Login with Github" 
                    icon={`${
                        <FontAwesome name="github" size={24} color="#FFFFFF" />
                    }`} 
                />
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use Touchable components: **TouchableHighlight, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Pressable.**

you can create your own button component:

```
const IconButton = ({ title, onPress, icon }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onPress}>
    <Text>{title}</Text>
    {icon}
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
...
```

And render it

```
<IconButton
  title={'Press me'}
  onPres={pressHandler}
  icon={<AntDesign name="caretright" size={24} color="black" />}
/>
```